# Do hidden animations cause a repaint?

Tags: browser, repaint

Given a webpage with a Javascript animation running on a timeout, does the browser check whether the element being animated is hidden or is it cheaper for the browser to fire a repaint?

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but thought I'd throw it out there - Yes the browser knows internally if what needs to be repainted is in the viewport and prioritises the repaint accordingly (so changes the user will see happen faster). Firefox has the mozAfterPaint func which fires after repaint, and the mozPaintCount property which continually increments with every repaint and can be checked accordingly.

I am looking for a cross-browser solution for establishing when there has been a repaint but it is much harder in other browsers.